# How to select a random element from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I am trying to select a random element from an array of strings and save it in my database.

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
myConnection.Open();
string Update = string.Format("UPDATE Ships SET InPort=True");
OleDbCommand myCommandUpdt = new OleDbCommand(Update);
myCommandUpdt.Connection = myConnection;
myCommandUpdt.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataReader drdrShipsRead = myCommandUpdt.ExecuteReader();

string[] Randominporta = { "True", "False", "False" };
// Testlabel.Text = Convert.ToString(Randominport[randomNumber]);

int iNumber = 1;
while (drdrShipsRead.Read())
{
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 3);
    string myAddingQuery = string.Format(" UPDATE Ships SET InPort= " + Convert.ToString(Randominport[randomNumber]) + " WHERE ID= " + iNumber + "");
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myAddingQuery);

   string myCommand.Connectionresult = myConnection;
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    iNumber++;
}
```

It does not work.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? The intention of this website is not to just fix a problem and you being happy with the given solution. Next time, you should be able to do this yourself. So please post your problem with a descriptive error (message) and we can explain to you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: "I am having the hardest time" is not an error message: please explain the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: Really need to see your error message.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do this is:

```
var a = new List<string> { "True", "False", "False" };

int index = random.Next(strings.Count);
var name = a[index];
a.RemoveAt(index);
return name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @CodesInChaos, I think code in the question is generally right but you don't declare your array correctly,

Try,

```
var randomImport = new [] { "True", "False", "False" };
```

---

It would be less brittle to do this

```
var randomImport = new [] { "True", "False", "False" };
var randomNumber = random.Next(0, randomImport.Length);
```

or,

```
var randomNumber = random.Next(
    randomImport.GetLowerBound(0),
    randomImport.GetUpperBound(0) + 1);
```

Comment: "`maxValue` The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned."

Comment: Still not working :(  its running but not modifying the database

Comment: @MoeiiYounes, there is no code in the question concerned with database manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Jodrell answer, you should modify the below line to include quotes to the SET InPort value.

```
    string myAddingQuery = string.Format(" UPDATE Ships SET InPort= '" + Convert.ToString(Randominport[randomNumber]) + "' WHERE ID= " + iNumber + "");
```

Comment: I edited out the SQL bit from the question because that is actually a separate question - sorry.

Comment: There is no error message. It runs but does not modify the database.

Comment: @tomfanning  I think, you should have left his question as is as I can see there may be problem with other part of code too.

Comment: @Ramesh I do feel that the SQL part should be a separate question but to prevent confusion I have restored the rest of it.